# How to use controller outside ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am developing a shopping cart app. I have created a directive which shows product details.

This directive is placed in between `ng-repeat`.

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products">
    <productEl product=product></productEl>
</div>
```

This product directive also contains "Add To Cart" button. Now, I would like to handle it in my controller from where this product list is instantiated. 
In my app config I am using `ui-router` where I initiated my `productListController` with `as a` syntax. How do I do that?

Comment: You can directly add method on ngClick on "Add To Cart" button where in it will accept the product that you passed in.
Can you post more code plz. Controller code?

Comment: `<productEl product=product on-add="vm.addToCart(product)"></productEl>` and create binding `onAdd: '&'`.

Comment: Thanks , I am working on ur suggestion.I will get back to you if any problem

Comment: Its working as expected. Thanks for help...

Answer (score 0):

as per dfsq

```
<productEl product=product on-add="vm.addToCart(product)">
 </productEl>
```

and create binding onAdd: '&'. –

live demo is

[here](https://plnkr.co/edit/meEcOD?p=preview)

I got answer